# equal video dimensions have same aspect ratio

Tags: dimensions, aspect-ratio

I uploaded a test video on YouTube with a 2.39:1 aspect ratio and YouTube converted it into the following qualities: 240p, 360p 480p, 720p, 1080p.
I downloaded the 1080p video to check its dimensions and they were 1920 x 664, or an aspect ratio of 2.89:1.

Does that mean that "1080p videos" don't need to have a 16:9 aspect ratio?

Let's say I have two videos, both 1920x1080.

1. Does that mean that both videos have same aspect ratio of 16:9 ?
2. Does that mean videos qualified as 1080p need to have:

   1. dimensions 1920x1080
   2. aspect ratio 16:9

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1080p) says "1080p is a set of HDTV high-definition video modes that are characterized by **1080 horizontal lines** of vertical resolution and progressive scan. The term assumes a widescreen aspect ratio of 16:9, thus implying a resolution of 1920 × 1080 (2.1 megapixels)," although no credible source is cited.

YouTube/Google define their interpretation of 1080p in [YouTube Player API Reference for  Embeds: Playback quality](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_quality):

> Quality level hd1080: Player height is 1080px, and player dimensions
>   are 1920px by 1080px (for 16:9 aspect ratio) **or 1440px by 1080px (for
>   4:3 aspect ratio)**.

I've never heard of a 2.89 aspect ratio. 16/9 = 1.7̅ 1920 x 664 is really strange. Maybe it's a bug in YouTube's converter. But I guess you could gain more control by uploading video which you've already converted to a standard aspect ratio yourself.

Comment: By the way, you could improve your question. Your "Does that mean..?" statements seem to draw conclusions unrelated to your postulates. More importantly, you don't state your goal.